# Change the color of a word in text from green to red when the cursor moves over it

Tags: output-formatting

This example displays text that changes from green to red when clicked:

```
DynamicModule[{col = Green},
  EventHandler[
    Style["first second third fourth", FontColor -> Dynamic[col]], 
    {"MouseDown" :> (col = col /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Red})}]]
```

I want text where the word "second" change from to red when the mouse is over it.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps I've missed something, but I see no reason to use low-level functions like `EventHandler`. I think you can use `Mouseover` at top-level to accomplish what you trying to do.

```
grn[txt_String] := Style[txt, Darker[Green]]
red[txt_String] := Style[txt, Red]
Row[{grn["first "], Mouseover[grn[#], red[#]]&["second "], grn["third fourth"]}]
```

With this code "second" changes from green to red when the mouse cursor it moved over it.

[image: result]

Comment: was of very great help, thanks

Comment: @Andres. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.

Comment: Sorry, but now, if the text was more big. This code can result: `Row[Dynamic@ Style[#, If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Green], 48, "Section"] & /@ {"Experiencie", "leads", "us", "to", "believe",  "that", "the", "motions", "of", "physical", "bodies", "are", 
   "controlled", "by", "interactions", "between", "them", "and", 
   "their", "surroundings"}, Spacer[5]]`

Comment: @Andres. I afraid you lost me with your last comment. I don't have a clue of what kind of response you expect me to make to it. It looks to me that it would be better addressed to kglr.

Comment: I was wrong, excuse me. Was to kglr

Answer (score 9):

```
Row[Dynamic @ Style[#, If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Green], 48, "Section"] & /@ 
  {"first", "second", "third"}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: was of very great help, thanks

Comment: Sorry, but now, if the text was more big. This code can result: `Row[Dynamic@ Style[#, If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Green], 48, "Section"] & /@ {"Experiencie", "leads", "us", "to", "believe",  "that", "the", "motions", "of", "physical", "bodies", "are", 
   "controlled", "by", "interactions", "between", "them", "and", 
   "their", "surroundings"}, Spacer[5]]`

Comment: @Andres, if you want to keep it in a single row, use a smaller font size (e.g. change 48 to 12) and smaller spacing (e.g, change `Spacer[5]` to `Spacer[1]`).

Comment: Is the text was more big. This is the code:                                                `text = "Experiencie leads us to believe that the motions of physical bodies  are controlled by interactions between them and their surroundings";
                                                                                                             StringSplit[text];
                                                                                                            Row[Dynamic@ Style[#, If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Green], 48, "Section"] & /@ StringSplit[text], Spacer[5]]`

Comment: Andres use `Row[Dynamic@ Style[#, If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Red, Green], 12, "Section"] & /@ StringSplit[text], Spacer[1]]`

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
DynamicModule[{col = Green}, EventHandler[
  Row[{
    Style["first ", FontColor -> Green],
    Style["second", FontColor -> Dynamic[col]],
    Style[" third fourth", FontColor -> Green]
    }],
  {"MouseDown" :> (col = col /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Red})}]]
```

Comment: Perfect. But, If I positioned myself on the word that I wanted, some code would also be possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What do you mean, "some could would also be possible"?

Comment: If I place the mouse on the word **"first"** it turns red when I click.

Comment: was of very great help, thanks